# How should I go about getting and processing an (Exchange) email attachment?

Tags: c#, attachment, exchange-server-2003

I need to get a zip file from an email attachment, unzip it and copy it somewhere.

What would be the way I should go about it?

I'm currently googling around things like 'Exchange API' and 'processing email attachments' and kind of hoping this kind of thing has been done before.

The environment will be Windows and Exchange 2003, and any coding will preferably be in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in the end using [Redemption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589254/using-redemption-outlook-with-a-user-other-than-the-logged-in-user-and-gettin) I had a couple of problems, hence the linked question but got there in the end.

You do need to have the Outlook client installed, and you need **full** mailbox rights (not just read) on whatever mailbox you are trying to access.

This question, [Read MS Exchange email in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652549/read-ms-exchange-email-in-c/652724#652724) asked a couple of weeks after mine got some good answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this some time ago, and the best way is to use WEBDAV. Every mail item can be referenced like a URL.

If you check out this [blog post on WEBDAV](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms877930(EXCHG.65).aspx), it should show you the way.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to do this in .NET you will either have to write or purchase a POP3 or IMAP4 class library to communicate with the Exchange server.

Here is one example of a POP3 client from CodeProject:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/despop3client.aspx

Comment: Wrong - there are several ways to access Exchange from .Net (WebDav, Webservices etc)