# Using Redemption (Outlook) with a user other than the logged in user - and getting errors

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2003, outlook-redemption

I'm using Redemption dll (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) and I've created an exe that accesses my mail box.

I run the exe in Windows Scheduler under my username and it works fine, I get an email sent to me (see below code).

When I change the runas username in Scheduler to someone else and try to access their mail box Profile I get an error. System.IO.FileLoadException

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

    object oItems;

    //string outLookUser = "My Profile Name";
    string outLookUser = "Other User Profile Name";

    string ToEmailAddress = "abc.email@xyz.com";
    string FromEmailAddress = "abc.email@xyz.com";
    string outLookServer = "exchangeServer.com";

    string sMessageBody =
        "\n outLookUser: " + outLookUser +
        "\n outLookServer: " + outLookServer +
        "\n\n";

    RDOSession Session = null;

    try
    {
        rdoDefaultFolders olFolderInbox = rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox;

        Session = new RDOSession();
        RDOFolder objFolder;

        Session.LogonExchangeMailbox(outLookUser, outLookServer);

        int mailboxCount = Session.Stores.Count;
        string defaultStore = Session.Stores.DefaultStore.Name;

        sMessageBody +=
        "\n mailboxCount: " + mailboxCount.ToString() +
        "\n defaultStore: " + defaultStore +
        "\n\n";


        //RDOStore rmpMetering = Session.Stores.GetSharedMailbox("Name of another mailbox");
        //objFolder = rmpMetering.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);

        objFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);

        oItems = objFolder.Items;
        int totalcount = objFolder.Items.Count;
        if (totalcount > 10) totalcount = 10;

        for (int loopcounter = 1; loopcounter < totalcount; loopcounter++)
        {
            RDOMail oItem = objFolder.Items[loopcounter];

            string attachmentName = string.Empty;
            foreach (RDOAttachment attachment in oItem.Attachments)
            {
                attachmentName += attachment.FileName + " ";


                if (attachmentName.Trim() == "Data.csv")
                {
                    attachment.SaveAsFile(@"C:\datafiles\" + attachmentName.Trim());

                    foreach (RDOFolder archiveFolder in objFolder.Folders)
                    {
                        if (archiveFolder.Name == "DataFileArchive")
                        {
                            oItem.MarkRead(true);
                            oItem.Move(archiveFolder);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            sMessageBody += oItem.Subject + " " + attachmentName + "\n";
            if ((oItem.UnRead))
            {
                //Do whatever you need this for                    
                //sMessageBody = oItem.Body;
                //oItem.MarkRead(true);
            }
        }

        System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(ToEmailAddress,FromEmailAddress
            , "Data File Processing-" + DateTime.Now.ToString()
            ,"" + sMessageBody);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Session = null;

        System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(ToEmailAddress, FromEmailAddress, "Error", sMessageBody + " " + ex.Message);

    }
    finally
    {
        if ((Session != null))
        {
            if (Session.LoggedOn)
            {
                Session.Logoff();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I try to run the same exe on another machine with me logged in I get this error,

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or ass
embly 'Interop.Redemption, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Interop.Redemption, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken
=null'
   at RPMDataFileProcessing.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Has anyone got any ideas on what I'm doing wrong, can Redemption be used in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working in the end by ensuring that the user you are logged in as, has 'full mailbox rights' to the mail box you are trying to see.