# Using Redemption dll (Outlook) on a 64 bit machine

Tags: c#, outlook, 64-bit, outlook-redemption

I have an exe that I have installed on my 32 bit machine, it loops through logged in users Inbox and works fine, (NB I still havent got it working for another user ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589254/using-redemption-outlook-with-a-user-other-than-the-logged-in-user-and-gettin)) any ideas there would be appreciated as well!).

But when I install it on 64 bit server I am getting this error:

```
Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {29AB7A12-B531-450E-8F7A-EA94C2F3C05F} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80004005.
```

I have registered the Redemption dll on the server ([see here](http://www.outlookforms.com/threads.aspx?forumid=5&messageid=12700)).

I have done this [running-c-app-32-bit-on-64-bit-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437271/running-c-app-32-bit-on-64-bit-machine)

NB.
The class id would appear to be `Redemption.RDOSession` ([see here](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/security.htm))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here was to install the Outlook client on the server.

Comment: Thanks for following up to your own question... Redemption can be a pain to work with but sometimes it seems like it's the only way.

Comment: Installing Outlook on an exchange server is however not advised because the mapi version is different from the one needed for exchange. The propper solution is to install the redistributable named Microsoft Exchange Server MAPI Client and Collaboration Data: Objects: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E17E7F31-079A-43A9-BFF2-0A110307611E&displaylang=en

Comment: As of Exchange 2010, it no longer installs or uses the MAPI system on the machine where Exchange is running. You can install Outlook on the same machine just fine. That being said, the standalone version of MAPI is a better choice if your code needs to run in a service, but it does not support Unicode PST and MSG files.

Answer (score 4):

Hanner de Jager nailed it on the comment, but this deserves a full fledged answer.

All you need on the server is to install the  [Microsoft Exchange Server MAPI Client and Collaboration Data Objects](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E17E7F31-079A-43A9-BFF2-0A110307611E&displaylang=en)

Outlook is not needed. That's the beauty of Redemption.