# submitting data via email to websystem

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I'm working on a task system and I'd like to be able to submit a task to the system by emailing it to a particular address.

I'm thinking I could set my user by the sender, the task subject by the subject and the task comments by the text of the email.

Not sure the version of Exchange we have available if that matters but I'm running .net 3.5 and using C#.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Charlie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following post about monitoring an Exchange mailbox with c#:

[Read MS Exchange email in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652549/read-ms-exchange-email-in-c)