# WCF Windows Service Monitor and process emails

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, service

I need your suggestions in solving this issue. Here is the requirement.
We have a Microsoft Exchange server and we have a service email account docs@mycompany.com.

We have scanners all owner the company when a user scans a document and email is sent to docs@mycompany.com as attachment.

Now I need to write a Windows service which needs to monitor that email account and whenever an email is received, read the attachement and store it in the database.

My question is, is it possible to do something of this sort?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help: [Read MS Exchange email in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652549/read-ms-exchange-email-in-c)

It's not quite a WCF service, but you should be able to create a service to monitor the account.