# C# reading Emails from MS Exchange

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server

Hi I am new to c# and have been asked to read in the title and contents of emails that arrive in a particular email account and them store them in SQL. I initially thought this must be easy but I cannot find any simple tutorials or samples.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Check [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652549/read-ms-exchange-email-in-c): something similar already discussed.
Mainly, you can use :

- [Exchange Web Services Managed
  API](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c3342fb3-fbcc-4127-becf-872c746840e1)
- IMAP
- POP3

If you will use EWS here is some sample :

```
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1); // depends from Exchange server version 
    //service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential( "{Active Directory ID}", "{Password}", "{Domain Name}" );
    service.AutodiscoverUrl( "First.Last@MyCompany.com" );
    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
          new ItemView( 10 ) );
    foreach ( Item item in findResults.Items )
    {
       Console.WriteLine( item.Subject );
    }
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. I have since been told the exchange servers only have IMAP, the servers are a mix of exchange 2003 and 2007.
So I am looking for some sample code for IMAP, either in C# or vbscript. Also there is no budget to buy libraries etc. 
I'm quite stuck here, any other helpful links would be greatfully received.
Thanks

Comment: this is a good sample. I tried to test in a console applictoin, but I get this error :

"The Autodiscover service couldn't be located." 

when service.Autodiscover("mdr@domain.com"); is executed. 

I'm in the same domain so I don't pass credentials per API documentation.

I've also installed the Exachange Webservice API per your reference. 

why is autodiscover not working? What else am I missing?

thanks

Comment: @user472092 check here - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchange2010/thread/5617c82f-b0c3-4591-8a40-4fc590091ed9/