# How to auto process emails when they arrive?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, email, process

i have the current scenario:

1. my app generates for each user an
   valid system email address of form
   lets say: uuid@website.com
2. when an user has a problem/question he can send an
   email from any address to that
   predefined system email address
3. the app should receive the emails sent by the user and process them(check for spam, insert in db)

in this scenario a possible first solution that i had in mind was to pool the emails addresses on a 15 minutes period, process them(spam or not spam) in an external desktop app(or similar) and insert them in a database.

because i want to do this in .net, C#, SQL server 2008, and it should run on a webserver is the below solution possible using WCF?

- i create a WCF webservice that when an email is received by an email address it captures it and starts the processing procedure.

One problem i see with WCF from the start is that i don't think that it can auto react, the only way i used wcf until now was only for calling it directly and receiving a result. So i think another layer should be put between the email server and the wcf service and that layer should "react" when something is received.

the main idea is to process the emails as they arrive not to be pulled out of the inbox periodically.

any pointers? thank you

Comment: Do you mean you want to write an SMTP server?

Comment: @Jappie: i thought of that also..but honestly i'm trying to find an "easier" way if any. if i start to write a smtp server then i need to test that also so if i had to choose between writing an smtp server and fetching emails periodically i'd choose the later.

Comment: Can you explain *>and it should run on a webserver*? Physical machine (the server running some website) or IIS/etc?

Comment: @KMan:it should run on the physical machine.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. A web service cannot capture anything for you. You will have to call(using an .ashx/or etc) the web service. That is what the web services are for, to be called.

> the app should receive the emails sent by the user and process them

It sounds like you are looking to develop an email client; if so, then how about:

- Create an email client app (for instance [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmostafa/RbmIMailPlus03292009040548AM/RbmIMailPlus.aspx))
- Create a windows service, to help process the mails.

Assuming that you've tailored the client program, the windows service would *work-with* the client, look for new messages, and processes them accordingly.

For email client examples, checkout:

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26606/82449) answer
- And [this article](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/06/c-mail-reader/)

Answer (score 0):

If connecting to Exchange 2007 SP1 or later Exchange Web Services looks like the best approach:

[Read MS Exchange email in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652549/read-ms-exchange-email-in-c-sharp)