# How do I receive email as part of an integrated processing scheme in dotnet 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, imap, email, pop3

Here's the situation.  Using a C# program, I have to POST big chunks of XML data to a third-party web site.  This web site accepts the POSTs (via http), then puts them in a queue.  Sometime later, when their server gets around it it, it processes my data and emails me back the results (using an email address that's in an XML element in the file).  The contents of the email messages are themselves XML.

My friendly local system administrator has created a dedicated Exchange mailbox for this purpose.

The question to you gurus is this: is there a simple, reliable, debugged API to use C# to grab  these messages from the dedicated exchange mailbox, and purge them when I'm done?

I'm aware that I could write some code to use POP3/TCP.  But I really don't want to reinvent the flat tire.  :-)   Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read MS Exchange email in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652549/read-ms-exchange-email-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question to you gurus is this: is
>   there a simple, reliable, debugged API
>   to use C# to grab these messages from
>   the dedicated exchange mailbox, and
>   purge them when I'm done?

Excahnge has a full set of web services you can use.

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119.aspx

Best you can do. Otherwise look at [Read MS Exchange email in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652549/read-ms-exchange-email-in-c) - the same answers apply. Thus voted to close.