# How do I access Outlook mails with ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I'm trying to write an asp.net (using c#) app that accesses my Outlook mailbox and display the messages. I searched on google but couldn't find useful info, any help is appreciated?

Comment: This is a strange one - perhaps you explain the reasoning behind this decision?

Comment: Outlook as in your client application? Or do you by "outlook" mean your "mail account"? Or perhaps the exchange server, that already has a web interface?

Comment: I think by "Outlook", OP means "Outlook".  There is only one Outlook, you know...

Comment: Outlook is often paired with [Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Exchange_Server).  In those cases Outlook is merely a viewing client (albeit with a local cache of the data), while Exchange holds the relevant data.  Take a look at [EWS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangefaqs/archive/2008/01/23/exchange-web-service-ews.aspx) for that purpose.

Comment: @gmagana: There are actually multiple Outlooks (client, web, office, ...).
But considering he wrote "Outlook mails" he may not mean that literally, it never hurts to ask for clarification... He may want the mails (that are on mail server), not Outlook interop... Got it?

Comment: @Jaroslav: Hmm no, there is only one Outlook.  The others you mention have different names, hence are different products.

Comment: Which Outlook? Microsoft Office Outlook 2003/2007, Microsoft Outlook 97-2011, Outlook Express 4.0-6.0, Outlook Web Access?

Comment: @Jaroslav you are right, I only want to access the mails nothing else. I'm using MS Outlook 2003. I want to access the mails that are in my Outlook and display the mailfrom, subject & body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Exchange then you can use Exchange Web Services to read emails.

Please see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb408417.aspx)

Comment: That's what I'm using. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Also I provide a simple code sample for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652549/read-ms-exchange-email-in-c-sharp/6622250#6622250

Answer (score 4):

You must be aware of the fact that outlook is running on user local machine, and your ASP.NET application is running on some server and there is no way that your server side ASP.NET code can use Outlook local data.

AFAIK only way to do something like that would be creating outlook addin that will export all mails to ASP.NET application

Comment: I'm using MS Outlook 2003, I don't think it's possible to create an addin in MS Outlook 2003?

Comment: Yes, it's possible : [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289167%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2004/03/21/93712.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)

Comment: bakula Outlook is running on Exchange Server 2007. Do you have some code to connect to ES2007?

Comment: no, sorry Massimo, it would be best to ask another question, and I am sure that you will get some answers

Answer (score 2):

Be very careful that you do not attempt to access Outlook on the server side by using the Automation interfaces. All of the Microsoft Office desktop applications are written to be run by an interactive user in a process with a message pump, with all synchronization happening via the UI. When you run them in a multi-threaded environment like ASP.NET, horrible things will happen. If you're lucky, the application will simply crash.

If you're not lucky, you can suffer from data corruption, random crashes in unrelated code, and all the other things that happen when an application corrupts memory.

You may also violate your license if the people accessing the Office application through your web site are not individually licensed to use the application on their desktop.

Comment: The people that will use the application will have the rights to use it. The application needs only to access my mails and display them, that's all. I don't see what could go wrong.

Comment: @Massimo: didn't you get the part about it just doesn't work in a server environment? Don't waste your time. There are easier ways to torture yourself if you like that sort of thing.

Comment: @John: haha, I don't torture myself. But I really want to access them :p that's all.

Comment: @Massimo: attempting to use an Office application from a server application like ASP.NET is torturing yourself. Don't do it. Take it from someone who learned the hard way.

Comment: @John: Outlook is running on Exchange Server 2007. So it does work in a server environment

Comment: @Massimo: no, not at all. Outlook is not running in a server environment. Outlook is running on desktops, accessing server data from Exchange. This is in contrast to "running" Outlook from an ASP.NET application, which will not work.

Comment: It will not work if you put it on the server, you mean? Because now I can access Outlook mails directly from my asp.net

Comment: @Massimo: I mean Outlook, the program. Do not use Outlook, Word, Excel, or any other Office program from an ASP.NET page or web service. These are Desktop programs and assume a Desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to Outlook via C# (ASP.NET), but you can connect to your mailserver via POP3/IMAP to read the mail.

[IMAP Client library using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/imaplibrary.aspx)

Comment: This is not correct, you can indeed connect to Outlook with C#, look at the other answers that mention Outlook addins/Interop.

Comment: @gmagana: Indeed, you can create an connetion to outlook from addins or via interop, but from what I know you cannot create an interop from a webpage to your local Outlook-client. I may be wrong, but I haven't found a way to do that, except if you install a client on the computer, which you call with a URL-handler

Comment: I want to create a webpage that accesses my messages of Outlook. And display them on that webpage, that I've created.

Comment: @Massimo, Then you'll have to access the mailserver that you use in Outlook, and fetch the mails from the server directly. You cannot access the Outlook-application directly via a webpage. If you follow the link in my answer, you will find a library that helps you do this. A good tip is to save the mails in a database of some sort, since the connection to the mailserver takes some time.