# How to communicate with Outlook from a .Net web application

Tags: .net, outlook

I am developing an asp.net web application in C# which accesses a SQL Server database. The app is deployed on an intranet. I have a table in the database that contains the Users in the company that includes their email address.

In one situation I need to retrieve information about each user from their Outlook account. For example, their name and job title.

Also, wWithin my asp.net application, users will be scheduling meetings which they, and other people in the project team, will attend. I need to be able to communicate with Outlook and set the meeting in each user's Outlook account.

I have no idea how to do this and would welcome any pointers please.I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to communicate with the Outlook installed on the users machine through a web application.
You need to access the Exchange server directly using [EWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to integrate with Outlook, it's a client application.  Assuming your company uses an exchange server, this [article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/comcom/article.php/c10137__1) should help you get started.

Comment: Thanks for the link. In that article it says 'CDO is exclusively for applications that reside on the Exchange Server itself' - my app does not reside on the Exchange Server - it's on a different server. Should I still look at CDO?

Comment: Sorry, I should have done a little more research on this.  There appears to be a good question for dealing with exchange on stackoverflow:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652549/read-ms-exchange-email-in-c

Comment: Thanks for that. We're using Exchange 2007 so I can use the Exchange Web Services.